# How to set time with jquery keyup method?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to add time with jquery keyup method.
Here is my code:

```js
$("#textbox").keyup(function () {
    var text = $('#textbox').val()
    
    $("#output").val(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <textarea id="textbox" placeholder = "..." rows="5"></textarea>
      <br><br>
      <input type="text" id="output"/>
   </body>
</html>
```

Actually I want when I'm typing, the keyup function call every 5 seconds. 
Like:
I'm typing `The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog`.
Desired output: `T f t d` like this.
first lettert `t`. The keyup function is callded after 5 section. And i'm also typing. After 5 sec the secound word is `f` from 'fox'.
And continue like this....

Have any way?

Comment: So you want to print the letter entered every 5 seconds?

Comment: Yes. One important things. Suppose I'm typing 30 words in 60 seconds.
Then keyup function call every 5 seconds. Then desire output is 12 words.
Clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to bind a `one()` event handler every 5 seconds. Note that you would need to use `keypress` instead of `keyup` for the case sensitivity of the character which is typed to be respected. Try this:

```js
addKeyup();

function addKeyup() {
  $("#textbox").one('keypress', function(e) {
    $("#output").val((i, v) => `${v} ${String.fromCharCode(e.which)}`);
    setTimeout(addKeyup, 5000);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="textbox" placeholder="..." rows="5"></textarea><br /><br />
<input type="text" id="output" />
```

Comment: If I send the output to a ajax call instead of div. Then what to do? 
Like-


`var testMsg = {message: "typing"};
ajaxCall('http://localhost/test.php', testMsg);`


I want to sent the output here instead of div.

Answer (score 1):

```
let lastKeyTime = 0;
$("#textbox").keyup(function () {
    if (lastKeyTime < Date.now() - 5000) {
        const outputElement = $("#output");
        outputElement.val(outputElement.val() + this.value.slice(this.value.length - 1));
        lastKeyTime = Date.now();
    }
});
```

But be aware, that when using `keyup` instead of `keydown` and you press two keys partially simultaneously (what happens all the time when typing fast), it will add the last pressed key to your list.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var typingTimer; 
  
$('#textbox').keyup(function(){
  clearTimeout(typingTimer);
  typingTimer = setTimeout(function(){
    $('#output').val($('#textbox').val());
  }, 5000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="textbox" placeholder = "..." rows="5"></textarea>
      <br><br>
      <input type="text" id="output"/>
<script>
  
</script>
```